# iOS app lacks App ID Prefix. UniversalLinks is not enabled for the app. Where to enter the App ID?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-dynamic-links

I get the Firebase Dynamic Link error

> iOS app lacks App ID Prefix. UniversalLinks is not enabled for the
>   app.

The weird thing is, that I have 3 ids

1. Bundle ID (8NF32DY4EL.app.myapp.ios)
2. Team ID (EASLU367HG)
3. App prefix (Q6AUGEP5N5)

When I go to the Firebase settings, it only offers me to add a Team ID. The field for the bundle ID is grayed out. I can't find a place to add the App prefix.

That's how the Apple App Site Association File looks like

```
{
"applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [{
        "appID": "EASLU367HG.8NF32DY4EL.app.myapp.ios",
        "paths": [
            "NOT /_/*",
            "/*"
        ]
    }]
}
```

The appID field in the json is [TEAMID][BUNDLEID]. There is no App prefix. The 8NF32DY4EL is part of the Bundle ID (I know it's weird).

Where can I set the App prefix in Firebase?

Here are the 3 Apple IDs from https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/bundleId/edit
[image: Apple IDs]

Here are the Firebase settings from https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project
[image: Firebase settings]

Here are the dynamic link errors
[image: dynamic link errors]

Comment: Double check the problematic bundle id, it could very well be an old id you have used in the past, before changing the bundle id to the current value.
That means you also removed the old app from firebase and added a new one with the current bundle id. So, the warning is actually for the deleted app.
Is this the case?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I also got this warning when creating a firebase dynamic link.

For my case, I realized the auto generated Bundle ID under Google Cloud Console > API & Services > Credentials > OAuth 2.0 Client IDs > iOS client is wrong (eg: lack of one 'e'). The warning no longer exist after I corrected this.

[image]

Comment: +! for this, in my case we had changed the bundleID and GCP added an additional row for the new ID.  had to delete the old ID from GCP and the warning went away

Comment: Worked for me, we had an old bundleID lying around which we were not using anymore so deleting that helped us

Comment: Only this worked for me on July of 2023 (i've updated every oauth2.0 key)