# How long does it take after app has released for Dynamic Link to open in App Store?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

It’s been a few days since my app has released in the App Store. I have updated the App ID in the project settings.

But when clicking on the the Dynamic Link, the app preview does not work.

It still shows an [empty App Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fFc6.jpg) with an Open button that doesn't actually show the app in the App Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue was caused because I changed Bundle ID in the middle of development and this creates different certifications in GCP.

More information here: [iOS app lacks App ID Prefix. UniversalLinks is not enabled for the app. Where to enter the App ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59034670/ios-app-lacks-app-id-prefix-universallinks-is-not-enabled-for-the-app-where-to)

Answer (score 0):

Within 24 hours of app approval, dynamic links start opening in AppStore.
Please check if you have implemented everything correctly.

Comment: I have the correct app ID in the code and listed in the project settings. The dynamic link even include the isi paramater with the correct App ID.

When I switched the app ID to some other app that has been in the app store for a while and generated a new dynamic link, the preview worked correctly and even opened the app store.